# How to call multiple functions using if statement?

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, matrix

I want to perform the following function using if statement which has variables in it. Consider three cell arrays A, B and C of size 16 x 16 each.for example I'm just taking 4 x 4 cell arrays.

```
 A = A B C D            B = C A B D          C = 0 2 1 3               
     D C B A                B D A C              3 2 3 1              
     C B D A                A B A D              2 1 0 1                     
     B A D C                D A A C              3 2 2 2
```

with respect to the values in C I need to perform functions on A and B as follows,

```
if C == 0
   Out = B;
elseif C == 1
   Out = XX(A,B);
elseif C == 2
   Out = complement (B);
elseif C == 3
   Out = NX(A,B);
end
```

Here complement, XX and NX are the functions that are to be called. I tried the following code but somehow 'if' statement is making it hard to get the results. I've defined the functions as well as the code I used to perform the above operation.

```
   for i=1:1:16
      for j=1:1:16
         if C(i,j) == 0
            O(i,j) = B(i,j);
         elseif C(i,j) == 1
               O(i,j) = XX(A(i,j),B(i,j));
         elseif C(i,j) == 2
               O(i,j) = complement(B(i,j)); 
          elseif C(i,j) == 3
               O(i,j) = NX(i,j);
          end
       end end
```

The function complement is as follows

```
  function [Q]=complement(P)
  [W1,W2] = size(P);
  Q = zeros(W1,W2);
  P1 = cell2mat(P)
  for i=1:1:W1
     for j=1:1:W2
         if P1 == 'A'
           Q(i,j) == 'D';
         elseif P1 == 'B'
               Q(i,j) == 'C';
         elseif P1 == 'C'
               Q(i,j) == 'B';
         elseif P1 == 'D'
               Q(i,j) == 'A';
         end  end  end
```

The function XX is as follows

```
  function [Q] = XX(T,P)
  T = cell2mat(T);
  P = cell2mat(P);

  Q(T == 'A'  & P == 'A') = 'A'; Q(T == 'A'  & P == 'B') = 'B'; Q(T == 'A'  & P == 'C') = 'C'; Q(T == 'A'  & P == 'D') = 'D';
  Q(T == 'B'  & P == 'A') = 'B'; Q(T == 'B'  & P == 'B') = 'A'; Q(T == 'B'  & P == 'C') = 'D'; Q(T == 'B'  & P == 'D') = 'C';
  Q(T == 'C'  & P == 'A') = 'C'; Q(T == 'C'  & P == 'B') = 'D'; Q(T == 'C'  & P == 'C') = 'A'; Q(T == 'C'  & P == 'D') = 'B';
  Q(T == 'D'  & P == 'A') = 'D'; Q(T == 'D'  & P == 'B') = 'C'; Q(T == 'D'  & P == 'C') = 'B'; Q(T == 'D'  & P == 'D') = 'A';
```

The function NX is similar to XX only substitution differs. I don't know where I'm going wrong either in the functions or in the 'if' statement. When I run the code the first if statement and the 'first if statement' from the complement function alone are getting executed, the remaining functions are not performed. Thanks.

Comment: Your pseudo-ifs and actual ifs do different things. How did you determine the functions are not called? If they are not called at all, then the problem cannot be in them naturally.

Comment: So, is `O` a numeric or cell array?

Comment: O is a cell array @Divakar

Comment: Try wrapping the outputs with braces : `{XX(A(i,j),B(i,j))}` and so on. Initializing `O` before the start of loops might be a good idea too.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm not sure about whether the other functions are called, but the first condition of the complement function is executed when I see the results.All the remaining conditions and the two other functions have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If A, B, C and O are all cell arrays, MATLAB would not proceed with `C(i,j) == 0`, since `C(i,j)` is a cell array and `0` is numerical.

Instead it will pop you an error (`Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'`).

If you are running your first piece of code as script, have a check on your workspace and see what C and C(i,j) exactly is.

If you want to keep A, B, C and O as cell arrays, I would suggest using cell array element operators such as `C{i,j} == 0`, `O{i,j} = complement(B(i,j))` since `B(i,j)` is a cell but output of `complement` function is numerical.